# Azure DevOps: Copy files to task failed with "Not found SourceFolder: D:\a\1\s\$(Build.SourceDirectory)"

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am building a pipeline in Azure DevOps for Machine Learning.
I created multiple steps starting from creating workspace, compute target, train and register the model, when I am trying to copy the files I am getting this error.

The step, I used is:

[image]

Error I am getting is:

[image]

Comment: Double check the documentation. It's $(Build.Source**s**Directory)

Answer (score 2):

Double check the documentation. It's `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)` Source**s**, not Source.